# I get an error when building nginx with docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to build springboot, nginx, mysql with docker, other stacks work fine, but nginx returns the following error

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh

10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

2022/06/14 03:41:48 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:11

nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:11
```

I think the error is a grammatical error, Below is the content of the nginx/conf.d/app.conf file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

The error log says there is a problem in the 11th line in app.conf, but I do not know the nginx syntax, so I have no idea what the problem is. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing an ending ```}``` for the root server block.

Comment: The error tells you exactly the problem - "*nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:11*".